# Swift resizing images (ALAssets) from Photo library for thumbnails

Tags: swift, uiimageview, image-resizing, alassetslibrary, cgimage

I am looking for solution how can I show thumbnails of images saved in photo library. I know there is method for thumbnail but result is too small (and for opposite fullScreen size is too big). I would like to set custom size of thumbnail which I want. I was trying to search for any solution but I think it was too complicated. For now I have these methods for showing thumbs:

```
func setFromAlbum(album:ALAssetsGroup) {
    //self.imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage:album.posterImage().takeUnretainedValue())

    album.enumerateAssetsWithOptions(NSEnumerationOptions.Reverse, usingBlock: {
        (asset: ALAsset!, index: Int, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
        if ((asset) != nil) // first non-nil element will be the recent asset
        {
            var assetRep: ALAssetRepresentation = asset.defaultRepresentation()
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: assetRep.fullScreenImage().takeUnretainedValue())
            stop.initialize(true)
        }
    })
}
```

and this for showing thumbnails of photos:

```
func setFromAsset(asset:ALAsset) {
    let assetRep: ALAssetRepresentation = asset.defaultRepresentation()
    let image = UIImage(CGImage: assetRep.fullScreenImage().takeUnretainedValue())
    self.photoImageView.image = image
}
```

I tried this but without success:

```
func setFromAsset(asset:ALAsset) {

    let imageOptions:[NSObject: AnyObject] = [
        kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize : 20
    ]
    let assetRep: ALAssetRepresentation = asset.defaultRepresentation()
    let imageRef = assetRep.CGImageWithOptions(imageOptions).takeUnretainedValue()
    let image = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
    self.photoImageView.image = image
}
```

I tried more keys in dictionary with different values but can't get any working. I found that maybe method `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex` could help me but examples were only in Objective C and it was too much for me to get it working.

So can someone help me how can I create thumbnails with custom size from ALAssets? With great showing performences. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
let objAlAsset = arrayImages.objectAtIndex(0)  as! ALAsset
var image = UIImage(CGImage:objAlAsset.aspectRatioThumbnail().takeUnretainedValue())
let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
```

Comment: Please avoid giving code-only answers. Try to explain how your code solves OP's problem. Help those less experienced to understand your solution.